# Copying specific lines after a string match and using them to replace other lines in another file

Tags: python, regex

I recently started using Python 3 and I am wondering if someone here would be kind enough to help me figure out how to do the following:

Let us suppose that I have a file that looks like this:

```
Line 0
'Phrase/String that I am looking for'
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
```

What I want to do is

(1) Starting from the end of the text file, search for a specific `phrase/string`,

(2) once I found the string, I want to copy lines 3-5

(3) replace, say lines 9-11, in another file with lines 3-5 from my initial text file.

So far, I am only able to find my string but I can't seem to figure out how to do steps 2 and 3. Here is what I've written:

```
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as searchfile:
     for line in reversed(list(searchfile)):
          if 'my string' in line:
               print(line)
searchfile.close()
```

Again, I have tried some other things but my script works until this point. So, I am only including this.

Comment: Step 3 is a separate problem, but similar to the first problem

Comment: I thought the 'Phrase/String that I am looking for' is _after_ the 3 lines to grab ? Otherwise it needs clarification since the phrase is the trigger for the match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure checking from the end is necessary or logical so just iterate over the file content breaking if we find the line and taking the lines we want with islice, then use enumerate and fileinput.input with inplace=True to modify the other file adding the new lines in the appropriate place:

```
from itertools import islice
from fileinput import input as inp
import sys

with open("in.txt") as f:
    sli = None
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() == 'Phrase/String that I am looking for':
            f.seek(0) # reset pointer
            sli = islice(f, 2, 5) # get lines 3-5, o based indexing
            break
    if sli is not None:
        for ind, line in enumerate(inp("other.txt",inplace=True)):
            if ind in {8,9,10}: # if current line is line 9 10 or 11 write the next line from sli
                sys.stdout.write(next(sli))
            else: # else just write the other lines
                sys.stdout.write(line)
```

other.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

After:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
12
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Padriac. To answer your question, I want to start the search from the end of the file because there may be more than one instance in which the desire string shows up. In this case, I only want to copy certain lines after the last time the string shows up in my file (first time if the file is read from the bottom). PS I did not need to use the f.seek(0) line. Just mentioning it for other users future reference.

Comment: @theCHemist90, worries, so you are copying based on the line number of the first occurrence of your search string?

Comment: If you had a huge file that you did not want to read into memory, you could always still go line by line updating using enumerate where the last time you find it will be your index

Comment: I was just gonna ask you about that. I am trying it now with a much bigger file and it is not doing anything. Would you mind showing me what you mean? To be more specific, I want my script to constantly check for the input file until a specific string shows up, at that point I want the script to do the search for the other string "starting from the bottom" (the one we have been talking about up until now) and do the line replacement. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I will throw an example together later when I get  a chance

Comment: Thanks, Padraic. I figured out though.

Comment: No worries, you just have to keep updating the index every time you encounter the line then at the end you will have the last index

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the 3 lines in part 1 and 2.

```
 # (?m)[\S\s]*((?:^.*\r?\n){3})^.*phrase

 (?m)                  # Multi-line modifier
 [\S\s]*               # Greedy, grab all up to ->
 (                     # (1 start)
      (?:                   # Only 3 lines of unknown text
           ^ .* \r? \n 
      ){3}
 )                     # (1 end)
 ^ .* phrase           # Nex line contains phrase
```

Comment: Thanks for responding!